# Keeping specific column data while aggregating and summing other columns

Tags: r

I am new to R, and using a medium-sized retail store's transactional data to practice. I'd like to create a data frame that has each customer's percentage of purchases in different categories of products, as well as a sum of their total purchases. This way, we can send marketing emails to people with a demonstrated preference in a given category, but exclude people who have purchased less than five times.

Sample data (except with nearly 100 categories in reality and about 250,000 rows):

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+------+------+------+
| Transaction | Customer_ID | Email              | Cat1 | Cat2 | Cat3 |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+------+------+------+
| 55          | 1           | email@address.com  | 1    | 0    | 0    |
| 55          | 1           | email@address.com  | 1    | 0    | 0    |
| 56          | 2           | email2@address.com | 0    | 0    | 2    |
| 57          | 3           | email3@address.com | 3    | 0    | 0    |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------+------+------+------+
```

Step 1: To aggregate by customer ID, I've used the following code:

```
segmented <- aggregate(df[4:6], list(Customer_ID=orders$Customer_ID), FUN = sum)
```

Step 2: To make those aggregated numbers into percentages, I used the following code:

```
segmented_percentage <- cbind(id = segmented[, 1], segmented[, -1]/rowSums(segmented[, -1])*100)
```

However, I lost email addresses in Step 1, and when I try to merge data frames with the below, it's never finished processing (and I've waited a few hours).

```
merge(segmented_percentage, df)
```

In short: how would I put these many pieces back together to get emails with demonstrated preference and total purchases?

(Many thanks for all of Stack Overflow's other answers. What I accomplished above was entirely the result of Googling and finding good answers here.)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Email` also as the grouping variable to get a column of 'Email' in the 'segmented', assuming that a particular 'Customer_ID' has the same 'Email'.

```
segmented <- aggregate(.~Customer_ID+Email, df1[-1], FUN=sum)
```

If we want to create the columns in the original dataset, use `mutate` from `library(dplyr)`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
         group_by(Customer_ID) %>% 
         mutate_each(funs(sum= sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), starts_with('Cat'))
```

We get the percentage from the 'Cat' columns and assign the output to replace the columns with the percentage.

```
ind <- grep('Cat', names(df2))
df2[ind] <- df2[ind]/rowSums(df2[ind])*100
```

Or we can use `prop.table` with `margin=1`

```
df2[ind] <-  100*prop.table(as.matrix(df2[ind] ), 1)
```

---

We can also do this using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), change the `class` of the columns we want to change as `numeric` (`lapply(.SD, as.numeric)`).  The columns to be selected can be specified in the `.SDcols` and we can assign (`:=`) the output back to the columns with the numeric column index.  Grouped by 'Customer_ID', we loop through the columns 4:6 using `lapply` and get the `sum`.  We use `Reduce` with `+` to do the elementwise sum of the `lapply` output (which is similar to the `rowSums`), divide the `sum` by the `Reduce` output within `Map` and assign the output to 4:6 columns.

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, (4:6) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols=4:6][,
   (4:6) := {tmp <- lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
             Map(f1, tmp, Reduce(`+`, tmp))}, by = Customer_ID, .SDcols=4:6]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Transaction = c(55L, 55L, 56L, 57L), 
Customer_ID = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L), Email = c("email@address.com", "email@address.com", 
"email2@address.com", "email3@address.com"), Cat1 = c(1L, 1L, 
0L, 3L), Cat2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Cat3 = c(0L, 0L, 2L, 0L)),
.Names = c("Transaction", 
"Customer_ID", "Email", "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, in my effort to make things clear, I labeled the columns simply. In reality, they all have unique names, such as FC, BA, AGE, HP, and so on. Is there a way to use your great code with unique column names?  (I have already used your first line of code with great success -- thank you!)

Comment: @UMG If they have unique names, you can use the column index.  For example, here we can use `mutate_each(funs(sum), 4:6)`.  Check the `?select`.  It have a number of options

Comment: I fear that the ind subset -- with all the unique column names -- is persistently a list. `ind <- df2[c(4:99)]` and `ind <- as.data.frame(ind)` won't help, and I get an error of "invalid subscript type 'list'" when trying to replace with a percentage.  But I'm sure if the column names in my question was accurate, your coding would work.

Comment: @UMG Based on the example, `df2[4:6] <- df2[4:6]/rowSums(df2[4:6])*100` worked.  The `ind` in my code is just a column index, but your `ind` is subset of columns.